# XCode Can't Find Imported header from framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am getting an error that it can not find the header file, but I have added the file via "link binary with library" under Build Phases.

The file is WhirlyGlobeComponent.h

and I imported... #import "WhirlyGlobeComponent.h" and it said that the file can not be found.

What could I doing wrong. I have already cleaned the project.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop the `.h and the .m` file into your swift project. Then Xcode should create a `Briding-Header.h` file for you. In there you have to add the `.h` file:

```
#import "WhirlyGlobeComponent.h"
```

After that, you should be able to use the WhirlyGlobeComponent without any additional imports in your swift files.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I am not sure if I am doing the right thing for that. 

I created a Swift Project but I am importing code from WhirlyGlobe which was created in ObjC. So I created a new .m .h file with the bridging header file along with it. 

With the .h .m files I was just going to copy and paste all of the code from the WhirlyGlobe tutorial and then try to link it to the ViewController.Swift to run it is. 

Im not sure if that is the correct way. http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/tutorial/your_first_globe.html 

Thanks again for your help!